# How to convert simple Actionscript 1 to Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

I sometimes have to edit an old .fla file. The problem is that I updated to a newer version of Flash and now I can't export .swf's with actionscript1 anymore. The code is very simple, it just shows you how much you would save if you were paying $17.99/month vs whatever your current bill is. So if the starting value for the slider is 19 (the value on load), the monthly savings (onthly_savings.text) would be $1.01 & savings over 6 months (six_months.text) would be $6.06. If the slider has been moved, then those two values are calculated based on the slider ratio:

```
this.onEnterFrame=function(){
    curr_bill.text=mySlider.ratio+19;
    ratio.text = (mySlider.ratio+17.99); 
    if (curr_bill.text=='19'){
        six_months.text='$6.06';
        monthly_savings.text='$1.01';
    }else{
        monthly_savings.text = '$'+(curr_bill.text-17.99);
        six_months.text = '$'+((6*curr_bill.text)-107.94);
    }
}
```

Also there is this script which is on the slider itself:

```
this.ratio=0 ;
dragger.onPress=function(){
    this.startDrag(true,0,0,line._width,0);
    this.onEnterFrame=function(){
        ratio=Math.round(this._x) ;
    }
}
dragger.onRelease=dragger.onreleaseOutside=stopDrag;
```

How would I rewrite this to make it work in actionscript 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I rewrite this to make it work in actionscript 3?

The first thing you would do is create an ActionScript 3 FLA. From there, analyse the properties and functions that you're currently using, and Google the equivalent AS3 implementations. From there, one piece at a time, you'll be able to rewrite your existing code as ActionScript 3.

For a quickstart, I would [read about how event listeners work](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html). They replace the old method of adding `onClick`, `onEnterFrame` etc handlers to objects.